# Error when trying to split a column using powerquery in Azure Data Factory -UserQuery : Expression.Error: An error occurred invoking 'Table.AddColumn'

Tags: csv, powerquery, azure-data-factory

I get the following error when trying to split a column by space delimiter on PowerQuery in Data Factory :

UserQuery : Expression.Error: An error occurred invoking 'Table.AddColumn': We can't get the expression for the specified value.

What is causing this and how would I go about resolving it?

Many thanks

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pycip.png)

The PowerQuery itself is :

```
let
  Source = dedupedetipscsv,
  #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(Source, "Candidate", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, true), {"Candidate.1", "Candidate.2"}),
  #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter", {{"ApprovedDate", type text}}, "en-GB"), "ApprovedDate", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, true), {"ApprovedDate.1", "ApprovedDate.2"})
in
  #"Split Column by Delimiter1"
```

Comment: I don't see `Table.AddColumn` in your M-Code.  Is there something you are not showing us?

Comment: Hi @RonRosenfeld thank you for your response. I believe I've worked out  what the issue is. According to the Microsoft documentation, Table.AddColumn is not a supported M Query when using PowerQuery in Data Factory.  I've had to do the column split in a later stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

> **Note:** Power Query will split the column into as many columns as needed. The name of the new columns will contain the same name as the
> original column. A suffix that includes a dot and a number that
> represents the split sections of the original column will be appended
> to the name of the new columns.

In the Table.AddColumn step might refer to variable which is a List.  You need to refer to #"Renamed Columns" which is the last step that results in a table.

Split columns by delimiter into columns |  [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/split-columns-delimiter#split-columns-by-delimiter-into-columns)

Make sure : An alternate for split by length and by position is listed below | [M script workarounds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/wrangling-functions#m-script-workarounds)

```
Table.AddColumn(Source, "First characters", each Text.Start([Email], 7), type text)
Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted first characters", "Text range", each Text.Middle([Email], 4, 9), type text)
```

Comment: Hi @ipsitadash-mt, thank you for your response. I believe I've worked out  what the issue is. According to the Microsoft documentation, Table.AddColumn is not a supported M Query when using PowerQuery in Data Factory.  I've had to do the column split in a later stored procedure

Comment: Thank you so much for the update. Glad that it got resolved nocoyote5374